# How can I make AutoHotkey hotkeys work regardless of the program opened?

Tags: autohotkey

When I have FeedBack 0.96 opened, AHK shortcuts do not respond (main concerns here are the volume controls). I could just alt-tab out of the window, but that would actually require alt-tabbing out of the window.

I did try running AHK as administrator, it didn't change anything.

Comment: If you're running your program as an administrator, the AHK script will need to be run as an admin also.

Answer (score 0):

1. Always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!
2. In case, you are launching FeedBack 0.96 first and after launching your AutoHotkey script, then it is possible that FeedBack 0.96 uses the same hotkey combination that your script and they are interfering with your script hotkeys. In that case you have two options:

   a. Change hotkey combinations of your script to hotkeys that are not used by FeedBack 0.96.

   b. If it is possible, change hotkey combinations of FeedBack 0.96 to hotkeys that are not used by your script. Check FeedBack 0.96 settings for it.

   c. Also you can try to first launch your AutoHotkey script and after FeedBack 0.96. In that case there is possibility that that your script hotkeys will override FeedBack 0.96 hotkeys.